# Does Phonegap mobile app require having "Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*" on server?

Tags: ios, cordova, mobile, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I'm developing an ios app with phonegap and Jquery. I'm facing an issue where sending ajax request failed due to the `xmlhttprequest-cannot-load No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource` error. I have white-listed all domain with `< access origin="*" / >` in config.xml.

However adding `Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*` on server could resolve the issue. But I don't want to use this approach because this exposes another security issue. Does Phonegap app requires this? I'm confused because someone says yes and someones says no, and official documentation doesn't mention this either.

Answer (score 0):

I just got the answer. phoneGap does not need this. What I'm experiencing is a known bug in the latest phoneGap (https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-app-developer/issues/169) which should be resolved soon.

Answer (score -1):

Not on the server no.

You can whitelist the origin though: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/guide_appdev_whitelist_index.md.html

Comment: Really? I don't see that in any of the documentation. Can you link me?

Comment: Hi @SubjectiveEffect, have you ever developed an phonegap app that works without Access-Control-Allow-Origin:* on server? I just want to know if my problem is caused by another issue.